# Java Swing and FXIssue With -XstartOnFirstThread

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

So, I'm currently trying to work with LWJGL3, which requires that `-XstartOnFirstThread` be used to initialize the GLFW window.  I'm also trying to create a launcher of sorts, which would require Java Swing or JavaFX.  However, I discovered that if that JVM argument is enabled, then neither Swing nor JavaFX will show the window, while Printing still works from the main method.  Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi");
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Angulus");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("hi again.");
}
```

Correctly outputs: "hi" and "hi again"  However, the frame never opens, and when the argument is removed, the frame works.  I have also tried putting the frame in a new thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hi");
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("hi again.");
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Angulus");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }).start();
}
```

Once again, the same issue arrises, this window will only open if there is no

`-XstartOnFirstThread` argument.  The same applies to JavaFX, the `start` method is never even called.

Comment: Have you tried `EventQueue.invokeLater` - as a general rule, it's how you should start Swing based Apps anyway

Comment: From I can gather AWT/Swing doesn't support `startOnFirstThread`, don't know about JavaFX

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't believe it worked, same issue occurs.